# What Do I Do? Unconfirmed Transaction For Almost 7 Hours :(

Tags: transactions, blockchain, block, unconfirmed-transactions

Sorry if I'm acting like a noob. Never had a transaction take this long and it's worrying :/ It's been about 6-7 hours and still no confirmations. Do I just wait it out? Please help! :(

The transaction ID is
c3cfa18f21ab69dce87b269643cc841f0c16b7e69683afaad14a25d4b0740277

EDIT: My wallet will not synchronize now either...

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the transaction confirmed shortly after you posted this. https://blockchain.info/tx/c3cfa18f21ab69dce87b269643cc841f0c16b7e69683afaad14a25d4b0740277 Should I delete this?

Answer (score -2):

You can thank the China government and internet censorship for the recent blockchain issues considering the two largest bitcoin miners are in China.

I have payments from yesterday almost 18 hours that have not finalized so you are not alone.

It is the beginning of the end for bitcoin brotha better start learning Monero!

Comment: This issue is unlikely to be caused by miners directly.